# How to return combinations of coordinates in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I would like to return combination of coordinates. Please take a look at the provided script and question below.

This script

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$y = 8;
$x_c = -200;
$y_c = 100;
$i = 20;
while($x <= 5) {
    echo "x is: $x <br>";
    echo "x_c is: $x_c <br>";
    $x++;
    $x_c = $x_c + $i;
} 
echo "<hr>";
while($y <= 13) {
    echo "y is: $y <br>";
    echo "y_c is: $y_c <br>";
    $y++;
    $y_c = $y_c - $i;
} 
?>
```

will return:

```
x is: 1 
x_c is: -200 
x is: 2 
x_c is: -180 
x is: 3 
x_c is: -160 
x is: 4 
x_c is: -140 
x is: 5 
x_c is: -120 
y is: 8 
y_c is: 100 
y is: 9 
y_c is: 80 
y is: 10 
y_c is: 60 
y is: 11 
y_c is: 40 
y is: 12 
y_c is: 20 
y is: 13 
y_c is: 0
```

**Question**

How can I return combination of this as pattern

```
x1,y1,x_c1,y_c1
x1,y2,x_c1,y_c2
x1,y3,x_c1,y_c3
...
x2,y1,x_c2,y_c1
x2,y2,x_c2,y_c2
x2,y3,x_c2,y_c3
...
x3,y1,x_c3,y_c1
x3,y2,x_c3,y_c2
x3,y3,x_c3,y_c3
```

or with numbers

```
1,8,-200,100
1,9,-200,80
1,10,-200,60
...
2,8,-180,100
2,9,-180,80
2,10,-180,60
...
3,8,-160,100
3,9,-160,80
3,10,-160,60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `$y` loop inside the `$x` loop. Here I am using `$yy` and `$yy_c` for the inner loop so that I can reset them back to the original `$y` and `$y_c` before entering the loop.

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$y = 8;
$x_c = -200;
$y_c = 100;
$i = 20;
while($x <= 5) {
    $yy = $y;
    $yy_c = $y_c;
    while($yy <= 13) {
        echo "$x,$yy,$x_c,$yy_c<br>";
        $yy++;
        $yy_c = $yy_c - $i;
    } 
    $x++;
    $x_c = $x_c + $i;
}
?>
```